# StackOverflowException was unhandled HResult=-2147023895

Tags: c#, stack-overflow, hresult, unhandled, httpunhandledexception

```
public void serialcek()
    {

            while (!exitThread)
            {
                foreach (ManagementObject currentObject in theSearcher.Get())
                {

                    try
                    {
                        textBox1.Text = currentObject["Size"].ToString() + " " + currentObject["PNPDeviceID"].ToString();
                        currentObject.Dispose();

                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        //    MessageBox.Show("Bişiler oldu bende anlamadım");
                        currentObject.Dispose();
                        //exitThread = false;
                    }
                }

            }
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            serialcek();
        }
```

i use thread. but its a few minute later an error. click button is exitThread make true. than 5 min later give an StackOverflowException was unhandled HResult=-2147023895 error.

thanks for help.

Comment: Because you are calling serialchek() recursively with no exit condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calling `serialcek()` recursivly without stopping and by that causing a stack overflow.

P.s. use [finally](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dszsf989.aspx) with `try\catch` to prevent code duplication:

```
public void serialcek()
{

        while (!exitThread)
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject currentObject in theSearcher.Get())
            {
                try
                {
                    textBox1.Text = currentObject["Size"].ToString() + " " + currentObject["PNPDeviceID"].ToString();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    // MessageBox.Show("Bişiler oldu bende anlamadım");
                    //exitThread = false;
                }
                finally
                {
                   currentObject.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
        Thread.Sleep(100);

        if(<condition>) // add your condition here
        {
           serialcek();
        }
    }
```